# How to import Swift Package in App already added to Workspace of App

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I am using Xcode 12.4, I created an app "App".

After that, I created a Swift Package "MyLibrary" via `File > New ... > Swift Package ...`, and chose the option to immediately add it to the workspace "App":

[image]

I want "App" to be an example app of how to use the Swift Package, so it seems nice that I can develop the package + example app in the same window and things are grouped together:

[image]

The problem seems to be that I can't import "MyLibrary" for example in the `ViewController.swift`:

```swift
import MyLibrary // no such module "MyLibrary"
```

**Question**: How can the app import the swift package?

Comment: Have you added the library to your "App" target?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is that different from the "Add to" step I described?

Comment: Yes, select the project in your project navigator then under General select the "App" target and check if MyLibrary is listed under "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content". If not then add it using the "+" button

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It works. You want to write an answer? Maybe link the docs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have added the package to your project you need to add the library  to your "App" build target.

- Select the project in your project navigator then under General
- Select the "App" target
- Check if MyLibrary is listed under "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content". If not then add it using the "+" button – Joakim Danielson 25 mins ago

See also [Apples documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/organizing_your_code_with_local_packages)